# Get top 5 records based on average c# linq lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lazy-loading

I'm trying to get the top 5 records based on the average rating of the movie.

I have the following,

Movie.Cs

```
public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string YearOfRelease { get; set; }
        public int RunningTime { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MovieGenre> MovieGenres { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MovieRating> MovieRatings { get; set; }
    }
```

MovieRating.cs

```
 public class MovieRating
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }

var queryable = await _context.MovieRatings.AverageAsync(x => x.Rating);
```

This gives me the average of the whole MovieRatings table. What I'm trying to get is the linq equivalent of this SQL Query

```
select top 5 MovieId, avg(Rating) as AverageRating
from MovieRatings
group by MovieId
order by AverageRating desc
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to select the `Movie` entity, so you can take the average of the ratings inside the `OrderByDescending` method:

```
var query = _context.Movies
              .OrderByDescending(m => m.MovieRatings.Average(r => r.Rating))
              .Take(5);
```

---

However, for the SQL you want to:

1. Group by `MovieId`
2. Select `MovieId` and `Average rating`
3. Order by descending rating
4. Return the number of results you need

This query will replicate your SQL:

```
var queryable = _context.MovieRatings
                .GroupBy(m => m.Id)
                .Select(g => new { MovieId = g.Key, AverageRating = g.Average(s => s.Rating)})
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.AverageRating)
                .Take(5);
```

---

Comment: Hi @haldo, Is it possible to select the movie entity?

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryable = await _context.MovieRatings.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(5);
```

If "OrderByDescending()" is not available transform to a List<> first:

```
var movieList = await _context.MovieRatings.ToList();
var result = movieList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(5);
```

Comment: Almost correct. just missing the .Average()